# Check if a plugin already exists, if not, use files within my plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a plugin that requires Advanced Custom Fields, there's documentation on how to add it [here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/including-acf-in-a-plugin-theme/), the code is below:

```
// 1. customize ACF path
function my_acf_settings_path( $path ) {

    // update path
    $path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'lib/advanced-custom-fields/';

    // return
    return $path;

}
add_filter('acf/settings/path', 'my_acf_settings_path');


// 2. customize ACF dir
function my_acf_settings_dir( $dir ) {

    // update path
    $dir = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'lib/advanced-custom-fields/';

    // return
    return $dir;

}
add_filter('acf/settings/dir', 'my_acf_settings_dir');


// 3. Hide ACF field group menu item
add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', '__return_false');


/**
* Set Advanced Custom Fields to Lite mode, so it does not appear
* in the WordPress Administration Menu
*/
define( 'ACF_LITE', true );


// 4. Include ACF
include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'lib/advanced-custom-fields/acf.php' );
```

The problem is I need to check if the ACF plugin already exists before I include it within my plugin - as there's a clash otherwise. How can I do the following:

1) Check if the plugin already exists within Wordpress (there's a basic and pro version).

2) If it exists then use that version, if it doesn't then use the version within my plugin (i.e using the code above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`is_plugin_active()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) fits the bill, since you're only really concerned if it's installed *and* activated:

```
<?php
    if ( is_plugin_active('advanced-custom-fields') ) {
        // do something
    }
?>
```

If you need to check if it's installed (regardless of activation), you can also [check if it's inactive](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_inactive).

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the pluin already installed  by using

```
if( class_exists('acf'){
  //acf plugin already exist;
  //do something.
}
```

Comment: And what about plugins that don't use classes?